# WP Adminer - instead Modify field appeared a strange field with text. MySQL database editing

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress, adminer

I got a problem with the database on Adminer plugin page. Somehow, suddenly, instead Modify field appeared a strange field with the text.

[image: screen shot: strange field]

On this example text is where%5BD%5D=Y&where%5BBarCode%5D=9780753827666&where%5BASIN%5D=0753827662&where%5BAuthor%5D=Flynn%2C+Gillian&where%5BTitle%5D=Gone+Girl&where%5BSKU%5D=M456B14-09-10-15-55&where%5BSalesRank%5D=74&where%5BLowestPrice%5D=2.71&where%5BPrice%5D=2.70&where%5BMinPrice1%5D=0.00&where%5BMinPrice2%5D=2.68&where%5BMaxPrice1%5D=2.80&where%5BMaxPrice2%5D=40.00&where%5BOut%5D=FALSE&where%5BSale%5D=TRUE&where%5BForSale%5D=N&where%5BKeep%5D=FALSE&where%5BFees%5D=0.00&where%5BCurrentPrice%5D=2.80&where%5BFNSKU%5D=X000AC2VO9&where%5BCondition%5D=&where%5BQuantity%5D=9

Also, instead of button to select whole result appeared the field with the number 1. This happened to all the tables.

[image: missing button screen shot]

On phpMyAdmin everything is in order. However, on the plugin page I can't use the SQL command, not to mention that I can't check/select the rows.
I\'ve tried to uninstall and re-install the plugin, but the result is the same. I ask for emergency help. I should be grateful for any advice on how to fix it.